# Search data in C# from Database SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I want to ask you regarding for the searching in C# and why there is a Not Found statement if already found the answer or the data itself.

Here is the code:

```
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Plate Number: ");
                    string plateNumber1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    var searchPlateNumberDAL = new ParkingSystemDAL(_iconfiguration);
                    var listSlotParking = searchPlateNumberDAL.GetList();
                    listSlotParking.ForEach(item =>
                    {
                        bool searchItem = item.plateNumber == plateNumber1;
                        if (searchItem == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item.parkingId);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
                        }
                    });
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KTWG.jpg)

Comment: Are u refering to the "break" statement? to break out of the Loop after it has found the Value? 
If im understanding correctly check the "continue", "break", "return" statements in C# thats what you want

Comment: When you use a debugger you understand better whats going on. The code will loop through ALL data and prints not found when the number is not the same

Answer (score 0):

I think there some garbage value is present.

So, code will be

```
if(item.plateNumber.ToString().Trim().ToUpper() == plateNumber1.ToString().Trim().ToUpper())
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.parkingId);
}
```

you can also use Linq **Where**  expression instead of ForEach

```
if( listSlotParking.Where(x =>x.planteNumberplateNumber.ToString().Trim().ToUpper() == plateNumber1.ToString().Trim().ToUpper()).ToList().Count()>0)
{
 Console.WriteLine(item.parkingId);
}
```

Comment: still the same result, if i used else statement for not found.

Answer (score -1):

Try

> item.plateNumber.Trim() == plateNumber1.Trim()

Comment: still same result